# identify missing files and rename files in sequential using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have series of files in a folder eg. 1,2,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,17.  They all have the .mp4 file extension.  I would like to end up with a list of files in the folder in sequential order with no missing numbers by renaming files appropriately.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Would the result be files named 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 with the .mp4 extension?

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part is sorting the files in numerical order. The problem is both the DIR and SORT commands will sort file names alphabetically, so 10 would sort before 9. Not what you want.

You can solve this problem fairly easily with pure batch, but I have a better solution: [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) is a hybrid JScript/batch utility that can sort names numerically. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Using JSORT.BAT, the solution is quite simple:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\yourFolder"
ren *.mp4 *?.save
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'dir /b *.mp4.save^|jsort /n^|findstr /n "^"'
) do ren "%%B" "%%A.mp4"
popd
```

The first REN appends .save to the end of all .mp4 files (1.mp4 becomes 1.mp4.save) so that the final rename does not have any name collisions.

The real magic is in the FOR /F loop.

- DIR /B simply lists the files, order doesn't matter
- JSORT /N sorts the list numerically
- FINDSTR /N "^" adds a linenumber: prefix to each line. The line number is the desired new name

The FOR /F parses each line into the line number (the new name), and the existing file name. The rest is easy.

Comment: Fantastic!  Works brilliantly.  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @crecy - Don't forget to accept an answer if it fully answers your question to your satisfaction. Simply click on the checkmark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, awards you 2 rep points, and awards the poster 15 rep points. Only one answer may be accepted per question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get file names and sort them
cd "C:\FolderOfFiles"
for %%a in (*.mp4) do set "i=00%%~Na" & set "num[!i:~-3!]=%%a"

rem Rename the files in the proper order
set i=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set num[') do set /A "i+=1" & ren "%%a" "!i!.mp4"
```

If you want to insert left zeros in the new names in order to keep the same order in `dir` and `for` listings, replace the last part by this one:

```
rem Rename the files in the proper order
set i=1000
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set num[') do set /A "i+=1" & ren "%%a" "!i:~-3!.mp4"
```